# Python password generator problem according to the user requirement

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords, password-generator

I'm trying to write password generator
Who generats password according to the user requirement.
If the user enters more than twice a yes
It doesn't always work. 
Not all of the requirements will be in the password that the function creates.
I'd love to know how to solve this and get an explanation.

```
from random import randint
from secrets import choice
    def PasswordGenerator():
        print("Welcome to Password Generator\nYou can create a password with capital letters, lowercase letters, numbers, and special characters.\nDuring the password creation process, we will ask you which password you want.\n")
        while True:
            try:
                length = int(input("Please enter the length of the password you want to create:\nNote: The minimum length is 8 characters And enter Only integers\n"))
                while length < 8:
                    print("The minimum password length is 8 characters, please enter a valid integer number ")
                    length = int(input("Enter the length of the password you want to create:\n"))
                password_uppercase = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want upper case? \n")
                while password_uppercase != "yes" and password_uppercase != "YES" and password_uppercase != "no" and password_uppercase != "NO":
                    password_uppercase = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want upper case? \n")
                password_lowercase = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want lower case?\n")
                while password_lowercase != "yes" and password_lowercase != "YES" and password_lowercase != "no" and password_lowercase != "NO":
                    password_lowercase = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want lower case?\n")
                password_numbers = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want numbers?\n")
                while password_numbers != "yes" and password_numbers != "YES" and password_numbers != "no" and password_numbers != "NO":
                    password_numbers = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want numbers?\n")
                password_special = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want Special symbols?\n")
                while password_special != "yes" and password_special != "YES" and password_special != "no" and password_special != "NO":
                    password_special = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want Special symbols?\n")
            except ValueError:
                print("Enter Only integers")
            except:
                print("Oops you got an error! Please enter a VALID value")
            else:
                alphabet = ''
                if password_numbers == "yes":
                    alphabet += "0123456789"
                elif password_numbers == "YES":
                    alphabet += "0123456789"
                if password_uppercase == "yes":
                    alphabet += "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                elif password_uppercase == "YES":
                    alphabet += "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                if password_lowercase == "yes":
                    alphabet += "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                elif password_lowercase == "YES":
                    alphabet += "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                if password_special == "yes":
                    alphabet += "!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"
                elif password_special == "YES":
                    alphabet += "!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"
                password = "".join(choice(alphabet) for x in range(randint(length, length)))
                return password
                break
```

Comment: Shouldn't `for x in range(randint(length, length)))` simply by `... for x in range(length)`?

Comment: Also, you never make sure that a character at least is chosen in each of the categories. You have to change your approach, or check after generating a password that it meets your conditions, and if not, retry until it does.

Answer (score 1):

As you are creating a complete alphabet & choosing the characters randomly from it, it does not guarantee that at least one from each group (number, uppercase etc.) will be chosen.

You can fix it by keeping the groups separate in the alphabet. Then choosing atleast one from each. In the end you should shuffle the characters once to make sure that the order in the alphabet list is lost in the password generated.

```
import random

def PasswordGenerator():
    print("Welcome to Password Generator\nYou can create a password with capital letters, lowercase letters, numbers, and special characters.\nDuring the password creation process, we will ask you which password you want.\n")
    try:
        length = int(input("Please enter the length of the password you want to create:\nNote: The minimum length is 8 characters And enter Only integers\n"))
        while length < 8:
            print("The minimum password length is 8 characters, please enter a valid integer number ")
            length = int(input("Enter the length of the password you want to create:\n"))
        password_uppercase = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want upper case? \n")
        while password_uppercase != "yes" and password_uppercase != "YES" and password_uppercase != "no" and password_uppercase != "NO":
            password_uppercase = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want upper case? \n")
        password_lowercase = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want lower case?\n")
        while password_lowercase != "yes" and password_lowercase != "YES" and password_lowercase != "no" and password_lowercase != "NO":
            password_lowercase = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want lower case?\n")
        password_numbers = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want numbers?\n")
        while password_numbers != "yes" and password_numbers != "YES" and password_numbers != "no" and password_numbers != "NO":
            password_numbers = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want numbers?\n")
        password_special = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want Special symbols?\n")
        while password_special != "yes" and password_special != "YES" and password_special != "no" and password_special != "NO":
            password_special = input("Answer only with yes or no.\nDo you want Special symbols?\n")
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter Only integers")
    except:
        print("Oops you got an error! Please enter a VALID value")
    else:
        alphabets = []   # keep a list of alphabet groups 
        if password_numbers in ("yes", "YES"):
            alphabets.append("0123456789")  # include group
        if password_uppercase in ("yes", "YES"):
            alphabets.append("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
        if password_lowercase in ("yes", "YES"):
            alphabets.append("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
        if password_special in ("yes", "YES"):
            alphabets.append("!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~")
        password_chars = []  # construct the password as a list
        while len(password_chars) < length:  # keep choosing until length requirement is met
            for alphabet in alphabets:  # for each group
                password_chars.append(random.choice(alphabet)) # choose a character from the group
                if len(password_chars) > length:
                    break
        random.shuffle(password_chars) # shuffle to lose the order of groups from the generated list
        return "".join(password_chars)

print(PasswordGenerator())
```

Output:

```
Welcome to Password Generator
You can create a password with capital letters, lowercase letters, numbers, and special characters.
During the password creation process, we will ask you which password you want.

Please enter the length of the password you want to create:
Note: The minimum length is 8 characters And enter Only integers
8
Answer only with yes or no.
Do you want upper case? 
yes
Answer only with yes or no.
Do you want lower case?
yes
Answer only with yes or no.
Do you want numbers?
yes
Answer only with yes or no.
Do you want Special symbols?
yes

OnWw0=]7
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.
I noticed that if I request a length of 10 it returns a password at length of 12.
I also tried to come back to "try" after except ValueError with while true but it doesn't work.

Comment: Right. The password length would have been a multiple of the number of groups in alphabets. I've changed the answer to accommodate for that. 

For the ValueError part, I'd suggest keeping the input part separate from the actual password calculation. You can take input in a while loop & catch ValueErrors in the input part, the password construction part should remain the same.